# Bug on both clang and gcc on unqualified call

Tags: c++, gcc, clang, language-lawyer

The standard manifests:

> ## 6.4.1
>
> The lookup for an unqualified name used as the postfix-expression of a function call is described in [basic.lookup.argdep].
>   [ Note: For purposes of determining (during parsing) whether an expression is a postfix-expression for a function call, the usual name lookup rules apply.
>   In some cases a name followed by < is treated as a template-name even though name lookup did not find a template-name (see [temp.names]).
>   For example,
>
> ```
> namespace N {
>   struct A {};
>   template <class T> int f(T);
> }
>
>  int main() {
>   int x = f<N::A>(N::A());        // OK: lookup of f finds nothing, f treated as template name
> }
> ```

Both gcc and clang do not compile this simple program and they issue a similar diagnostic:

```
no templated name f found did you mean N::f?
```

This is clearly an implementation bug unless something is not clear. Should I fill in a defect report?

Comment: Could you please use the [stable.section.name] instead of 6.4.1. Numbering can change drastically between standards, the stable names do not.

Comment: Both GCC and Clang trunk compile this on godbolt.

Comment: What is wrong with this error message?!
1. The code shouldn't compile.
2. You use template brackets after the name, so it says that there is no such template name.
3. Proposal to use the namespace qualifier is good.
So what is wrong?!

Comment: @chris - The code fails to compile for me with any version of gcc on godbolt unless I specify `-std=c++2a`. And even then it only compiles with gcc 9 and gcc trunk.

Comment: @Omnifarious - Likely because it's a shiny new C++20 related change.

Comment: @SimoSimov - Shouldn't it be trying to look up `f` in the namespace of the arguments to `f`? Isn't that what argument dependent lookup is all about?

Comment: The text in question is not in my C++17 draft so it probably does come from C++20.  That said, [my c++20 draft](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/basic.lookup.unqual) doesn't have the same code as quoted, So I don't know where it comes from.

Comment: @Omnifarious ADL does not find function templates when parameters are specified

Comment: @StoryTeller - The OP should be explicit then about which version of the standard he or she is referencing and exactly which version of the compiler he or she is using.

Comment: @Omnifarious - No argument there

Comment: Wow, yes I was reading the standard from the `latex` sources generated here http://eel.is/c++draft/ and I was compiling with `std=c++17`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The rule that you quote is different in C++17. The change proposal: [p0846r0](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/p0846r0.html). If you are compiling for C++20, then the example should compile, and if it doesn't, then the compiler has incomplete C++20 support.

No compiler has stable support for C++20, which hasn't even been released yet officially (the feature list was recently frozen though), so some bugs are to be expected, as support for that future language version may not be complete.

The latest development version of both GCC and Clang successfully compile the example, so bug report should not be necessary.

---

The standard draft for C++17 says:

> [basic.lookup.unqual]
>
> The lookup for an unqualified name used as the postfix-expression of a function call is described in 6.4.2. [Note: For purposes of determining (during parsing) whether an expression is a postfix-expression for a function call, the usual name lookup rules apply. The rules in 6.4.2 have no effect on the syntactic interpretation of an expression. For example,
>
> ```
> typedef int f;
> namespace N {
>     struct A {
>         friend void f(A &);
>         operator int();
>         void g(A a) {
>             int i = f(a); // f is the typedef, not the friend function: equivalent to int(a)
>         }
>     };
> }
> ```

This example compiles fine in clang 5.0.0-3~16.04.1 as well as GCC 8.2.0.

Comment: That makes sense, I was using the latest draft found in http://eel.is/c++draft/ That being said, I am curious now why they changed it, especially when we are waiting for the proposed changes of Herb Sutters proposal (for ADL)

Comment: @KostasRim See the linked proposal document

Comment: @eerorikaI was unaware of this paper and I very much appreciate the link/reference. Thank you for the reply/edit and help :) I am curious if that got in during the Cologne meeting, I will take a look at the mailing list ;) – Edit, just read the paper Toronto and it received strong support (12 | 14 | 0 | 0 | 0).